# New DS 160 and new payment.... for old visa appointment

Tags: visas

I did not submit by DS160 and its been more than 30 days....but I booked my visa appointment.... and now I am unable to retrieve my application. I see some people mentioned that we can go-ahead an start new DS 160 and update profile..... do I need to make a new payment for new ds 160? and proceed with old appointment?